# Output is the same for every number?

Tags: c, pointers, math, output

This program is supposed to asks the user to enter a positive integer (the integer could be of any number of digits in the range of the integer type) and replace each digit by the sum of that digit plus 6 modulus 10. The program then should swap the first digit with the last digit before it displays the output.

A sample input/output:

```
Enter the number of digits of the number: 5
Enter the number: 92828
Output: 48485
```

For some reason with my code, no matter what number I enter, everything just comes out as 6. (so if I enter 5 numbers, I get 666666). I'm new to pointers, so is there an issue with that, or do I just have some math wrong? The program runs without any compiler warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void replace(int *a, int *b, int n);
void swap(int *p, int *q);

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int a[100], b[100];

    //Prompt user to enter number of digits
    printf("Enter the number of digits you'd like to replace: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    //Prompt user to enter the number to use
    printf("Enter  the number to use: ");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++);
        scanf("%1d", &a[i]);

    //replace function
    replace(a, b, n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d", b[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

void replace(int *a, int *b, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      *(b+i) = (*(a+i)+ 6) % 10;
    }
    printf("The output is: ");

    //swap function
    swap(b, (b+ (n-1)));
}

void swap(int *p, int *q)
{
    int t;
    t = *p;
    *p = *q;
    *q = t;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is absolutely correct except a silly mistake in the following code snippet.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++);
    scanf("%1d", &a[i]);
```

Why did you put a `;` after the `for` statement? It means your `for` loop is just iterating once (instead of 5 if `n = 5`). As a result, only the first digit input is considered given by the user but that too be stored in `a[5]` (considering `n = 5`), values stored in `a[0]` to `a[4]` are all garbage value.

Just remove the semicolon and update your code as follows.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    scanf("%1d", &a[i]);
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Always something simple. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The culprit in your code is the semicolon after the for loop:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)**;**
    scanf("%1d", &a[i]);
```

So the scanf that you wrote is basically out of the for-loop and stores the first digit into a[n].

Comment: It's always the little things. Without any compiler warnings I had no idea where to look. Thanks!

Comment: you could compile your code with -g and debug it with gdb :)

Comment: @ch.sarath i will suggest `cc -Wall a.c`

Comment: I'm not sure gcc will report empty for loop as a warning.

Comment: @ch.sarath It doesn't.